# Music Import does not work

Tags: applications, music

I imported an album into the Music app and when I disconnected the drive (a few hours later) all the songs came up with an error and the songs were never imported.

Under preferences, I selected 'Keep Music folder organised' and 'Copy imported files to Library'.

I imported the music by 'Import to Library...' in the gear menu.

Comment: Looking at /var/log/syslog I am getting a number of errors from io.elementary.m

Comment: Looking at /var/log/syslog I am getting a number of errors from io.elementary.m
- g_value_get_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed
- Read-only property 'read-only-view' on class 'GeeReadOnlyBidirSortedSet' has type 'GeeSortedSet' which is not equal to or more restrictive than the type 'GeeBidirSortedSet' of the property on the interface 'GeeBidirSortedSet'
- message repeated 381 times: [ noise_playback_manager_get_current_media: assertion 'self != NULL' failed]

I moved my library to another partition, the app may not have write access. How would I check?